why when i navigate from profile screen to login screen, the app navigate to home screen
i build an compose application and i want to logout and navigate to login screen but app navigate to home screen, i use bottom navigation bar and nested navigation.
this is the button that will logout:
@Composable
fun ProfileContent(rootNavController: NavController) {
    val authViewModel: AuthViewModel = viewModel()
    //sign out
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        onClick = {
        authViewModel.signOut()
        rootNavController.navigate("login"){
            popUpTo("profile"){ inclusive = true }
        }
    }) {
        Text(text = "Sign Out")
    }
}

this the routes:
object Graph {
    const val RootGraph = "root_graph"
    const val HomeGraph = "home_graph"
    const val AuthGraph = "auth_graph"
}

sealed class AuthRouteScreen(val route: String) {
    data object Login : AuthRouteScreen("login")
    data object SignUp : AuthRouteScreen("signUp")
    data object Forgot : AuthRouteScreen("forgot")
}

sealed class HomeRoutesScreen(val route: String) {
    data object Home : HomeRoutesScreen("home")
    data object Scan : HomeRoutesScreen("scan")
    data object Chat : HomeRoutesScreen("chat")
    data object History : HomeRoutesScreen("history")
    data object Profile : HomeRoutesScreen("profile")
}

this is the root nav:
@Composable
fun RootNavigationGraph() {
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(LocalContext.current as ViewModelStoreOwner)[AuthViewModel::class.java]
    val rootNavController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = rootNavController,
        route = Graph.RootGraph,
        startDestination = Graph.AuthGraph
    ) {
        authNavGraph(rootNavController = rootNavController, viewModel = viewModel)
        composable(route = Graph.HomeGraph) {
            HomeScreen(rootNavController = rootNavController)
        }
    }
}

this is the Auth nav:
package com.example.cardiolink.graphs

import androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.navigation
import com.example.cardiolink.viewModels.AuthViewModel
import com.example.cardiolink.views.ForgotPasswordScreen
import com.example.cardiolink.views.LoginScreen
import com.example.cardiolink.views.RegisterScreen
import com.example.cardiolink.views.SplashScreen

fun NavGraphBuilder.authNavGraph(rootNavController: NavHostController, viewModel: AuthViewModel) {
    navigation(
        route = Graph.AuthGraph,
        startDestination = AuthScreen.SPLASH.route
    ) {

        composable(route = AuthScreen.SPLASH.route) {
            SplashScreen(navController = rootNavController)
        }

        composable(route = AuthScreen.Login.route) {
            LoginScreen(navController = rootNavController, viewModel)
        }
        composable(route = AuthScreen.SignUp.route) {
            RegisterScreen(navController = rootNavController, viewModel)
        }
        composable(route = AuthScreen.Forgot.route) {
            ForgotPasswordScreen(navController = rootNavController)
        }
    }
}

sealed class AuthScreen(val route: String) {
    data object SPLASH : AuthScreen(route = "SPLASH")
    data object Login : AuthScreen(route = "LOGIN")
    data object SignUp : AuthScreen(route = "SIGN_UP")
    data object Forgot : AuthScreen(route = "FORGOT")
}

this is the Home Nav:
@Composable
fun HomeNavGraph(
    rootNavController: NavHostController,
    homeNavController: NavHostController
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = homeNavController,
        route = Graph.HomeGraph,
        startDestination = Utils.Home.route
    ) {
        composable(route = Utils.Home.route) {
            HomeContent()
        }
        composable(route = Utils.Scan.route) {
            ScanContent()
        }
        composable(route = Utils.Info.route) {
            InfoContent()
        }
        composable(route = Utils.History.route) {
            HistoryContent()
        }
        composable(route = Utils.Profile.route) {
            ProfileContent(rootNavController = rootNavController)
        }
    }
}

i am tried to use nested navigation but didn't work and also sue separate navigation but also didn't work

What's the difference between AuthScreen and AuthRouteScreen? In the same vein, Utils seems to have objects very similar to HomeRoutesScreen. Can you clear this up? Also, where is HomeNavGraph called? How is the relation between it and RootNavigationGraph?
